# Mutate state based on existing fields

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

With React-Final-Form, I am creating a control that allows users to be listed ina directory if a radio button is clicked. In the click handler, I wish to auto-populate a textbox with the user's first and last names. I am doing this with a mutator, and I'm hoping I can get confirmation that I am doing this correctly, as I couldn't find documentation about the `lastFieldState` property I'm leveraging:

```
  setDisplayName: (args, state, utils) => {
  const { firstname, lastname } = state.fields;
  const currentFirstName = firstname.lastFieldState.value;
  const currentLastName = lastname.lastFieldState.value;
  utils.changeValue(state, 'displayName', () => `${currentFirstName} ${currentLastName}`);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of the library here. I can confirm that you are doing things just fine.