# Mutator to covert text to uppercase

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I tried different ways to implement mutator to convert text to uppercase as soon as user input text in the text field. But was not yet successful. The [example](https://medium.com/@erikras/final-form-arrays-and-mutators-13159cb7d285) provided by Erick seems correct, but maybe I am missing something.

```
/** Converts a form value to uppercase **/
const upper = ([name], state, { changeValue }) => {
  changeValue(state, name, (value) => value.toUpperCase())
}


<Form
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  mutators={{
    ...arrayMutators,
    upper
  }}
  render={({
    handleSubmit,
    mutators: { push, pop, upper }, // injected from final-form-arrays above
    pristine,
    reset,
    submitting,
    values
  }) => {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Company</label>
          <Field name="company" component="input" onChange={(e) => upper('company')} />
        </div>
      </form>
    )}
  }
/>
```

It's throwing an error when calling `toUpperCase` on value as `value` is coming undefined there. Really appreciate any help!

**Update: 27-Oct-2018**

I have realized we can use parser too, to solve this problem:

```
upper = value => {
  return value ? value.toUpperCase() : ''
}


<Field name="company" component="input" parse={this.upper} />
```

Still looking for how mutator works and what's the error in my code.

Already Tried:
[Mutate state based on existing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026497/mutate-state-based-on-existing-fields)

[How to set/change Field value from external user action 🏁 React Final Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901016/how-to-set-change-field-value-from-external-user-action-react-final-form)

Answer (score 1):

As I know about react-final-form you can get this data directly 
I will suggest, you can use this code

`onChange={(event, value) => input.onChange(value.toUpperCase())}`

https://codesandbox.io/s/0x9y71nwyp

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This has solved my problem of converting text to uppercase. But I want to know how we can achieve it through mutator too.